# C String recursion stack copy or...?

Tags: c, string, recursion, memory, stack

Let's Assume that I have.

```
 char c[500];
```

I have this following function that I wrote for my assignement :
(Basically, it's a tree, infix order, if left node exist, write 0 (1 for right) to the buffer at i position, else write '\0' and print the buffer).

```
void imprimer_codes (node *b, char *c, int i) {
  assert(c);
  if (!b) return;

  if (est_feuille(b)) {
    c[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s:%c\n",c,b->symbol);
  }

  if (b->fg) {
    c[i] = '0';
    imprimer_codes(b->fg,c,i+1);
  }

  if (b->fd) {
    c[i] = '1';
    imprimer_codes(b->fd,c,i+1);
  }
}
```

Since I am using it recursively. I don't understand how the function can actually print multiple different buffer since there's multiple \0 into the buffer.

Is the pointer to the c[500] is copied to the stack memory? This might be the only explanation I can found.

Comment: Please post a complete code.

Comment: You might want to `return` after calling `printf` and/or think about whether ot use `if/else` rather than just `if`. The basic reason for getting multiple prints is that potentially each call of this function can result in two calls to this function __and__ one print

Comment: I think the fact that you use it recursively and that you try to store the chars into a buffer while doing it is a bit tricky.

Imagine you have` i = 5`
it can enter the `if (b->fg)` and the `if (b -> fd)` and both can then write at `c[5]` 
Maybe that is something you want to think about. The same behaviour can occur for yout `\0`...

Comment: @TimRandallI would assume that `est_feuille(b)` is `true` if the fields `fg` and `fd` are false. It should matter if there is a return.

Comment: `est_feuille` is .... ? `node ` is … ?

Comment: How do you check what is in your buffer. How do you distinguish a `'\0'` that was already there from a new one?

Comment: @Gerhardh but we cannot make any such assumption. We particularly can't assume that only one of `fg` and `fd` is true

Comment: `est_feuille` is french for `is_leaf` so I guess that would mean that there is no child nodes left

Comment: I would guess that `fg` and `fd` represent the left and right branches (g = gauche = left, d = droit = right)

Comment: This is a good time to start using a debugger. You can step through your code and see where you come along...

Comment: @4386427 - What a wonderfull world

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are trying to do but here is a tip.  Your handling of `i` seems wrong. As the recursion starts returning, you'll reuse "old" values of `i` and thereby overwrite values. More likely you need to pass `i` as a pointer like  `void imprimer_codes (node *b, char *c, int *i)` and then increment before the recursive call. But this is just guessing... Edit your answer to make the question more clear

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: @4386427 The 0 and 1 printed represent the path in the tree. With this sequence you can start at the root and follow left and right branches to get to the desired node. Therefore the index must be the "old" one after returning from one recursion.

Comment: @TimRandall I did not assume that only one of `fg` and `fd` is true. I do expect that more than one can be true. I only assume that it is not a leafe if one of them is true.

Comment: @4386427 the same index is reused after the previous line was printed. That's perfectly fine. Each leaf gets one line printed and the prefix can be reused to print the siblings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since I am using it recursively. I don't understand how the function can actually print multiple different buffer since there's multiple \0 into the buffer.

It is rather simple. As an example consider a tree,

```
   *
 /   \
x    ...
```

That is, with a leaf on the left and some subtree on the right.We start with,

```
i = 0, c = []
```

Your algorithm goes left first (still has to go right),

```
i = 1, c = [0]
```

This is a leaf so it adds null,

```
i = 1, c = [0, \0]
```

and prints. That branch is done so it backtracks and we have,

```
i = 0, c = [0, \0]
```

remember `i` is being passed by value but `c` is an array, and arrays are passed by reference. So then we go right,

```
i = 1, c = [0, 1]
```

and the null is gone.

Just one more example where the null is not overridden. Consider,

```
    *
  /   \
 /     y
x
```

You go twice to the left,

```
i = 0, c = []
i = 1, c = [0]
i = 2, c = [0, 0]
```

then you add the null and print

```
i = 2, c = [0, 0, \0]
```

since there's only a right branch at the root, that's where it will backtrack to,

```
i = 0, c = [0, 0, \0]
```

and then it goes right,

```
i = 1, c = [1, 0, \0]
```

and it's a leaf so we will add the null and print it,

```
i = 1, c = [1, \0, \0]
```

I think this should be enough to understand what's going on.

The point right after inserting a `\0` you backtrack to a smaller `i`, and continue building the new string  from there. So never at any point will you have a `\0` in a position before your current `i`.